# How to change UITabBar image dynamically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

At some point during runtime, I want to change the image for one of the tabs in my `UITabBar`. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1]
    setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-name"]
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The above gives me a `-[UITabBarItem setImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

If I use the `setImage` method without `forState` it works, but this method was deprecated in iOS 3.

I tried your answers, but now there's this weird blue line above the `UITabBar's` `UIIMage` I changed. Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Use `image` and `selectedImage` properties:

```
UITabBarItem *item = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
item.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
item.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_image"];
```

Also pay attention on [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitabbaritem_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarItem/selectedImage):

> By default, the actual selected image is automatically created from
>   the alpha values in the source image. To prevent system coloring,
>   provide images with UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal.

Comment: Does that explain the blue line above the tab bar? See the pic I just added.

Comment: @thisiscrazy4 I think YES, try to use `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` option for `selected image`.

Comment: Same thing, but now it's a grey line.

Comment: @thisiscrazy4 It seems that your image for UITabBar that has transparent part at the top. May be it is the reason?

Comment: Actually after looking into this more, I realized that the image isn't even being set to the new image. The properties for item are almost all nil, which means I don't think I'm accessing the correct UITabBarItem.

Answer (score 1):

`UITabBarItem` extends `UIBarItem` which has an `image` property.

Do:

```
[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-name"]];
```

Though it would be easier to read and debug as follows:

```
UITabBarItem *item = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[1];
item.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

though the question is very old and the answer by @visput absolutely working but for some one complete newbie like me

In your `UITabBarController` implementation

if while loading of the `UITabBarController` you want, put it in `viewDidLoad` method

```
UITabBarItem *item = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:ITEM_INDEX];// item index is the tab index which starts from 0
item.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
item.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
```

If you want to change it runtime like on selection of something, put this code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method